# Identifying an exercise

Tags: exercise, movements

I have been doing an exercise which I came up with (not saying I invented it) that I have not seen before and I was wondering if there was a name for it.

Imagine the cherry picker move we used to do in school. Similar to that. This also reminds me of a diagonal sit-up.

Stand with your feet apart past shoulder width. Place a dumbell 5-10lbs at one foot. With the oposite hand, reach down and grab it. Using your lower back and abs, come back to a standing position keeping your back straight. The arm with the dumbell should track your leg (as if it were on a rail). The lower and repeat.

When I'm doing 3 sets of 10 (10 lbs) or 2 sets of 10 (25 lbs) I can feel I've worked out my love handle area (internal obliques?).

Comment: Pictures or it didnt happen ;)

Comment: @Ivo No one was around to take pics :) I'll try to get a few of me doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to dub this exercise the "One-handed kettlebell cross snatch":

[image: kettlebell snatch]

Similar to the picture shown, but across the body.

Comment: close but not quite. The torso must be twisted since the arm has to track the leg but not raised above the waist. Basically like bending over then standing. I'll try to get some pics. Also +1 because I didn't think to use kettle bell.

Comment: Ok, so more like a deadlift than a snatch, right?

Comment: correct, more like a dead lift